# Select a folder, lookup for a specific filetype, and if afirmative write in textbox

Tags: vb.net, stream, folderbrowserdialog

I'm developing a program to seek for a specific file type (only one of a kind exists in one folder). 
I select the folder, scan it for the file type in case of he finds stream the file and write the query result on a textbox.

This is what i got so far:

```
For Each file1 In IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderA, file_A)
            Using fich_time As New StreamReader(file1)
                line = fich_time.ReadLine


                Try
                    myStream_time = file1.OpenFile()
                    If (myStream_time IsNot Nothing) Then

                        line = fich_time.ReadLine

                        While Not fich_time.EndOfStream

                            If line.Contains(" CPU Time for A Analysis") Then

                                If line.Contains("sec") = True Then
                                    txt_A.Text = line
                                    txt_A.Text = Replace$(txt_A.Text, Space(1), Space(0))
                                    txt_A.Text = Regex.Replace(txt_A.Text, "[^0-9.]", "")

                                Else
                                    txt_A.Text = line
                                    txt_A.Text = Replace$(txt_A.Text, Space(1), Space(0))
                                    txt_A.Text = Regex.Replace(txt_A.Text, "[^0-9.]", "")
                                    txt_A.Text = txt_A.Text * 3600

                                End If
                            End If
                        End While
                    End If
                Finally

                End Try

            End Using
        Next
```

The main error is the OpenFile method is a member of string, so far I know that but what function should I use to make this work??

Best Regards
Andre

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But I can see that your stream is not moving in the `While` loop. You probably forgot a `line = fich_time.ReadLine` inside this loop.

Comment: OpenFile() n'existe pas comme methode pour un streamreader et encore moin pour un string. Si je comprends ce que tu veux faire....Tu cherche pour un fichier en particulier et après tu recherche pour une ligne dans le fichier en mode texte qui contient des données dont tu as besoin et inscrit le tout dans un textbox. c'est exact?

Comment: When you send the file as an argument to StreamReader constructor, it is ready to read. You do not need a separate operation to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and don't forget to close your file

```
    For Each file1 In IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderA, file_A)
        Using fich_time As New StreamReader(file1)
            Try
                While Not fich_time.EndOfStream
                    line = fich_time.ReadLine
                    If line.Contains(" CPU Time for A Analysis") Then
                        If line.Contains("sec") = True Then
                            txt_A.Text = line
                            txt_A.Text = Replace$(txt_A.Text, Space(1), Space(0))
                            txt_A.Text = Regex.Replace(txt_A.Text, "[^0-9.]", "")
                        Else
                            txt_A.Text = line
                            txt_A.Text = Replace$(txt_A.Text, Space(1), Space(0))
                            txt_A.Text = Regex.Replace(txt_A.Text, "[^0-9.]", "")
                            txt_A.Text = txt_A.Text * 3600
                        End If
                    End If
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Finally
                fich_time.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    Next
```